# SQL date = like '%YYYY%' VS YEAR(Date) = 'YYYY'

Tags: sql, sql-server

When using SQL server, are there any benefits and what are the performances  of using = in a WHERE clause instead of LIKE?
e.g :  date = like '%YYYY%' VS  YEAR(Date) = 'YYYY'

THX

date = like '%YYYY%' VS  YEAR(Date) = 'YYYY'

Comment: Assuming this is in a `WHERE`, there are no benefits to either of those clauses, only detriments. Both clauses will be non-SARGable, and will perform poorly. if you want *good* performance, use date boundaries.

Comment: Both are awful but one can easily result n bad matches due to unctontrollable string conversions. Don't use either.

Comment: Frankly, both are bad choices. Consider an explicit range check --`WHERE [Date] >= 'yyyy0101' AND [Date] < '<yyyy+1>0101`. This is assuming your column is a proper date/time type of course, which it should be.

Comment: Time-based reporting becomes infinitely easier and faster if you use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a table with precalculated eg 20 years of dates with extra columns for years, months, weeks, quarters or any other reporting period and label you want. To get rows for a specific year you join the `Date` column with the Calendar and filter or group on `Calendar.Year`